Handling result of .NET Upgrade Assistant in Powershell
I'm using the .NET Upgrade Assistant CLI to upgrade some projects. I'm doing this by invoking the assistant via powershell scripts. I cannot find any documentation on how to parse the response of the assistant, the way it looks its just text.
At the very least I'd like to check for errors but the
$?

error checking always returns true, whether there is an error or not.
Is there a way to check these results or do I need to parse the string?

For executables, check $LASTEXITCODE immediately after it returns

@MathiasR.Jessen Have you actually tested this for the .NET Upgrade Assistant CLI or is this just general information about executables? I'm just getting "0" as a exit code for all my tests, despite some succeeding and some not.

The suggestion to inspect $LASTEXITCODE instead of $? to evaluate outcome of an executable invocation is generic advice - if the tool doesn't reflect the failures in its exit code then it's obviously no use :)
